# ANZSCO occupation

Tags: visa, working-visas, new-zealand, skilled-migration, certification

I am a Computer Engineer with 6 years of experience.
Applying for New Zealand's "Skilled Migrant Category Resident Visa"

Points can be gained for recognised work experience, that is matches the description of one of ANZSCO occupation.

I can't find anywhere any hints on whether I should have the work experience  attested. It seems to me, I don't need to do that. Could anyone confirm, please?

Here's a post from my blog of my thought and finding information process: 
https://movingtonewzealandstory.wordpress.com/2019/09/16/work-experience-znzsco-skilled-migration-new-zealand/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to prove experience for the expression of interest but will have to if invited to officially apply. Here's the official application booklet:

https://www.immigration.govt.nz/documents/forms-and-guides/inz1105.pdf

See page 10 for specific information about proving work experience.